# I forgot the birthday I used for my Facebook account: is my account lost?

Tags: facebook

I forgot the birthday I used for my Facebook account, and Facebook asks me for it to be able to have access to my account:

[image]

Is there any other way I can access my Facebook account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here.

1. Facebook has a bug. Go to facebook.com/help and file a report
2. You intentionally entered a wrong birthday that you now cannot remember

With 2, you *can* file a report but you set yourself up for a catch 22 since the whole point of the exercise is to confirm your identity, a real identity to which you agreed to in Facebook TOS. If I were you, I would use my words carefully when writing the report.